# Need a QNumberElement for QuickDialog

Tags: iphone, ios, forms, quickdialog

I have read all the classes of `QuickDialog`. But I can't find a element suits my need. I need a element that the value is `NSNumber`, and the keyboardType is `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`. Maybe I didn't notice one. Could someone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that the QDecimalElement?

https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/blob/master/quickdialog/QDecimalElement.m

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that.